# Proof of $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

So I have $$|a|=|(a-b)+b|\leq |a-b|+|b|\Rightarrow |a|-|b|\leq |a-b|$$ and $$|b|=|(b-a)+a|\leq |b-a|+|a|\Rightarrow |b|-|a|\leq |b-a|$$ now the next step in my book is listed as multiplying by $-1$ to get $$-|a-b|\leq |a|-|b|$$ Next they say that they combine these two inequalities now to get $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$. I can't seem to figure out the algebra they did to get this.

Comment: Because we define $|x|=\begin{cases}
x & x\ge0\\
-x & x\le0
\end{cases}$.

Substitute those two into that and observe.

Comment: They're using the fact that $|x| < y$ if and only if $-y < x < y$.

Comment: When you write $|x| \leq r$ you mean $ -r \leq x \leq r$. Now put $x = |a| - |b|$ and $r = |a - b|$ and your desired inequality means $$-|a - b| \leq |a| - |b| \leq |a - b|$$

Comment: A much easier way to handle this inequality is to note that in calculating $|a - b|$ we have the chance that $a, b$ are opposite signs and the calculation will actually involve addition of absolute values of $a, b$. On the other hand the calculation of $||a| - |b||$ will always involve subtraction and hence the result will be smaller or equal to $|a - b|$. Equality occurs only when $a, b$ are of same sign (or one of $a, b$ is $0$).

Comment: $|a|-|b|\leq|a-b|$ and $|b|-|a|=-(|a|-|b|)\leq|b-a|$

Answer (score 1):

We have $|a-b| = |b-a|$; we have $|b| - |a| \leq |b-a|$ iff $|a| - |b| \geq -|a-b|$. Use the previous result $|a| - |b| \leq |a-b|$ to conclude.